# хотел бы отслеживать, когда пользователь теряет роль discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-api

У меня есть команда, которая раз в час случайным образом определяет пользователя и дает ему особую роль, и я хочу, чтобы пользователь из этой роли дал другим роль, и у них дабы был по-типу клан. Но после того, как случайный человек теряет эту роль, а именно через час, я хочу, чтобы клан также был изменен, а именно те пользователи, которые были добавлены, роль была удалена из них.

````
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.default)
async def pd(ctx):
        gomo_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=800360472595267604)
        alyanc_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=801182180101324810)
        await ctx.send('```Итак гомо часа становиться...```')
        await asyncio.sleep(float(0.5))
        await ctx.send('```Барабанная дробь.....```')
        await asyncio.sleep(float(0.5))
        global user
        user = choice(ctx.channel.guild.members)
        if user == bot.user:
            print('бот гей часа')
            await ctx.send('```Увы но гомо часа стал я, альянс делать не буду,по этому просто давайте отдохнём```')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'``Эта: ``{user.mention}')
            await user.add_roles(gomo_role, alyanc_role)
            time = float(0.10)
            await asyncio.sleep(time * 60)
            await user.remove_roles(gomo_role, alyanc_role)
            await ctx.send(f'```Час подходит к концу по этому {user.display_name} лишаеться звания гомо часа.```')

#Альянс Command dont work
@bot.command(aliases = ['добавитьгомо'])
@commands.has_any_role('3 lvl', 800360472595267604)
async def add_pidor(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    if get(member.roles, id = 801182180101324810):
        await ctx.send('```Данный пользователь уже находиться в Альянсе.```')
    else:
        gomo_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=800360472595267604)
        alyanc_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=801182180101324810)
        if member == bot.user:
            await ctx.send('```Нельзя сделать альянс гомо с главным гомо сервера.```')
        elif member == ctx.author:
            await ctx.send('```Как бы нельзя самому себе выдать, ну ты клоун.```')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'```В Альянс гомо был добавлен {member.display_name}```')
            await member.add_roles(alyanc_role)
            if get(user.roles, id = 800360472595267604):
                for i in user.roles:
                    if get(user.roles, id = 800360472595267604):
                        break
                    else:
                        await ctx.send('```Альянс был разформлен так как гомо часа сменен.```')
                        await member.remove_roles(alyanc_role)```
````

Comment: лучше вопрос задавать на русском...

Comment: если онлайн переводчики убрать - как блестать знанием английского будете ?

Comment: Please translate your question into Russian or use StackOverflow in English. Thanks. / Переведите вопрос на русский или воспользуйтесь StackOverflow на английском. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

За отслеживание отвечает `@client.event` а именно `discord.on_member_update(before, after)`
т.е. он будет выглядеть так

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
   if len(before.roles)>len(after.roles):
      print('тут у человека стало меньше ролей чем раньше')
```

Вот соус: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?event#discord-api-events
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_member_update#discord.on_member_update

1. про ивенты
2. про on_member_update

Comment: Спасибо за помощь